# Array and ArrayList positional access performance

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

i just read this code example:
http://robaustin.wikidot.com/how-does-the-performance-of-arraylist-compare-to-array

what causing
j = INT_ARRAY[i]; 
to be three times faster than 
j = ARRAY_LIST.get(i)

I know that ArrayList internally uses an array. So i would like to know
in details what are the extra operations that add this time ( calling methods, casting, other JVM considerations etc..)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 0,0036s difference, are you serious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The performance will *very* much depend on the VM involved, and a variety of other considerations. The blanket statement at the start of that article leads me to suspect that the author has little clue about how performance varies on JVM - and the rest of the test code confirms that. It doesn't test for nearly long enough, nor does it use any JVM warmup period or anything similar. Oh, and it uses `INT_ARRAY.length` when testing the `ArrayList` version, meaning that one *potential* source of JIT optimization is removed. Really *not* a good article.

However, it's fairly easy to consider the things that ArrayList.get() involves beyond the normal array access:

- A nullity check (to see whether the ArrayList reference is non-null). This is in addition to the nullity check for the array itself, which is required for both the array and ArrayList cases.
- Potentially a virtual method indirection, depending on whether the JIT has managed to inline the call
- A bounds check - not the same as for the array access, as the size of the list is usually smaller than the length of the array.

Ultimately though, the performance of one single method call doesn't matter much. What mattes is whether that's significant in your actual use case. Does your application spend most of its time getting individual elements from a collection? Does it do so in the kind of loop shown in the article, which does nothing else and may therefore benefit from additional JIT optimizations in one case or the other?

Microbenchmarking is fun, but you need to be aware of its limitations when it comes to providing you useful information.

Comment: +1 for the world "nullity" ... I'm totally going to find an excuse to use this today.

Comment: I am asking this question from a theoretic point of view, and not a practical one. I am asking for the one main diffrence between the two: they both are objects on the heap, and both uses an array at the end.

Comment: @Yaron: But you're starting from a "practical" (but poorly measured) premised - that it takes three times as long to fetch from an ArrayList as from an array. To be honest, it *all* comes down to practicalities - things like how much bounds checking the JIT can optimize away, inlining, cache coherency etc. What benefit do you expect to get from a purely theoretical answer, when the practical details make so much difference to *real* performance?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but maybe the code example I gave was not good. Let me put it that way: Lets say I am in a job interview. The interviewer shows a piece of code that uses a positional access to an array, many times in a second, and says the performance of this pieces of code is critical. So he asks me :"will you use an Array or ArrayList?". so , I know Array is faster, but what is the one main big difference? How can I sum up the difference?

Comment: @Yaron: I would say I would benchmark the two in a real world situation and make the decision based on that. Yes, I could go into some of the differences I've mentioned above, but I'd focus on the fact that *theoretical* differences don't matter nearly as much as *practical* ones.

Answer (score 3):

The test is badly written.  You can't learn much of anything from it.

It is true that accessors like `get` take some time, but e.g. the Sun JVM can optimize many of those away to almost nothing.  In particular, `ArrayList` get needn't really take any significant extra time.

Here's a benchmark (written in Scala, but using Java's arrays and `ArrayList`) demonstrating just how small the difference is when you're actually using (all of) the values in your array:

```
object ArraySpeed {
  def ptime[A](f: => A) = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime
    val ans = f
    printf("Elapsed: %.3f seconds\n",(System.nanoTime-t0)*1e-9)
    ans
  }

  val a = Array.range(0,1000000).map(x => new java.lang.Integer(x))
  val b = new java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.Integer]
  a.foreach(x => b.add(x))

  var j = 0

  def jfroma = {
    var i=0
    while (i<1000000) {
      j += a(i).intValue
      i += 1
    }
    j
  }

  def jfromb = {
    var i=0
    while (i<1000000) {
      j += b.get(i).intValue
      i += 1
    }
    j
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    for (i <- 1 to 5) {
      ptime(for (j <- 1 to 100) yield jfroma)
      ptime(for (j <- 1 to 100) yield jfromb)
      println
    }
  }
}
```

Running it gives:

```
$ scalac ArraySpeed.scala
$ scala ArraySpeed
Elapsed: 0.324 seconds   // This is direct array access
Elapsed: 0.378 seconds   // This is ArrayList

Elapsed: 0.326 seconds
Elapsed: 0.389 seconds

Elapsed: 0.355 seconds
Elapsed: 0.349 seconds

Elapsed: 0.323 seconds
Elapsed: 0.333 seconds

Elapsed: 0.318 seconds
Elapsed: 0.331 seconds
```

And Scala bytecode for stuff like this is pretty much identical to the Java bytecode, so this is a pretty fair comparison.  (The `scala` command is just a wrapper to call `java` with the right library in the classpath.)

Answer (score 2):

It probabaly helps in figuring out what caused the difference (on his particular processor, JVM, OS, etc.) to look at the generated byte code.

For readFromArrayList:

```
   6:   goto    25
   9:   getstatic       #47; //Field ARRAY_LIST:Ljava/util/List;
   12:  iload_3
   13:  invokeinterface #116,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
   18:  checkcast       #17; //class java/lang/Integer
   21:  astore_0
   22:  iinc    3, 1
   25:  iload_3
   26:  getstatic       #25; //Field INT_ARRAY:[Ljava/lang/Integer;
   29:  arraylength
   30:  if_icmplt       9
```

For readFromArray:

```
   6:   goto    18
   9:   getstatic       #25; //Field INT_ARRAY:[Ljava/lang/Integer;
   12:  iload_3
   13:  aaload
   14:  astore_0
   15:  iinc    3, 1
   18:  iload_3
   19:  getstatic       #25; //Field INT_ARRAY:[Ljava/lang/Integer;
   22:  arraylength
   23:  if_icmplt       9
```

I don't know if I buy the "three times" difference, but whatever differences there are can be traced to the differences at op #13: aaload (for the array) vs. invokeinterface and checkcast (for the ArrayList).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the JVM has specific opcodes for working with arrays.  It's likely the performance difference is overhead of method calls and such.  Why not write a simple test case and use `javad` to have a look at what the code compiles down into.  That should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is not best way. I have 3 different approaches based on differnet situations:
1. When I have to do very big for cycle with low cost operations inside - yes improve access to data gives to you good percent of optimisation.
2. If case is same as 1. but with heavy operations inside - optimize access is just a very litle optimization - better is to optimize fields in object and operations with them.
3. Lots of cycles with heavy calculations and nothing more to optimize - make some 'bad practice' programming.
For example: Instead of returning new value every time - pass work variable to function and return result in it. It sounds stupid, but reduces variable creation and memory fragmentation. In my case this gived to me 15-25% better time. Reason? Reduced GC calls. No spend time to call constructors.

Answer (score -2):

Without checking the link posted and assuming that an array list is 3 times slower as you say then the speed difference is likely to vary accross JVMs, several things could influence the speed of getting a value back. The results from that article are likely to vary depending on the control variables in effect when performing the tests. A collection should not be surprisingly a bit slower either considering that various checks are completed before completing the operation. Adding to an arraylist for example calls

```
 public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    modCount++;
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (minCapacity > oldCapacity) {
        Object oldData[] = elementData;
        int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
            if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
            // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }
    }
```

As that clearly shows there are checks and data is copied and replaced.
So to put it simply there is no one answer, the test conditions are likely to affect the results.

Comment: It is going about lookup times and not insert times.